# Showing percetage in the loader

Tags: html, css, typescript

I am using angular then I have already my loader spinner then I want to have it a progress percentage inside the spinner.

Here is my code.

### HTML

```
<div class="loader" *ngIf="loading; else showWhenloaded"></div>
```

### TYPESCRIPT

```
export class PoCompletedComponent implements OnInit {

  check: checker[];
  mode: boolean;
  loading: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private poCompletedService: PoCompletedService,
  private location: Location,
  private router: Router
      ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.poCompletedService.checkData()
      .subscribe(check => {this.check = check;
        if (this.check){
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
      console.log(this.check);


  }
```

### CSS

```
.loader { margin: 100px auto; font-size: 25px; width: 1em; height: 1em; border-radius: 50%; position: relative; text-indent: -9999em; -webkit-animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease; animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); -ms-transform: translateZ(0); transform: translateZ(0); } @-webkit-keyframes load5 { 0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #00ffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7); } 12.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #00ffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5); } 25% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #00ffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 37.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #00ffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 50% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #00ffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 62.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #00ffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 75% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #00ffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 87.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #00ffff; } } @keyframes load5 { 0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #00ffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7); } 12.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #00ffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5); } 25% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #00ffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 37.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #00ffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 50% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #00ffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 62.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #00ffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 75% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #00ffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2); } 87.5% { box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(0,255,255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #00ffff; } }
```

---

Comment: and what percentage you wanna show?  do you have something that say the progress of your operation ?

Comment: process of the spinner

Comment: Yes can you help me?

Comment: the spinner is just an animation, it is not showing any progress. it's just spinning.

If you want to show a percentage that means something, you have to get some value of the current progress from somewhere. Also, there is thousand of ways to show percentage. make your request cleaner by explaining what you want to achieve exactly, and where are you stuck at.